# Valgrind for macOS Mojave 10.14.2? Any alternatives?

Tags: valgrind, macos-mojave

Ok, so I saw that someone asked this question over 4 months ago. But it has been a decent time since Mojave has been out. Does anyone know how to get it working or possibly any alternatives so that I can check my programs for memory leaks. I am a student, so cost does matter but this is a requirement for several of my classes. I would prefer not to have to use a virtual machine considering they never run well on Macs. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You could consider using Sanitizers, such as Address Sanitizer. Here is a link for Clang: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html.

Comment: The support for that states "OS X 10.7 - 10.11 (i386/x86_64)". I am on 10.14.2 which is a dramatic difference since how the OS handles the filesystem and much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options here.

1. You can use `XCode` for development and run the code in `Profile` mode.
2. You can start `Instruments` and attach to process
3. You can run the code and use `leaks` to determine the leak size

```
> leaks 2419
Process:         LeakingTheMemory [2419]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/LeakingTheMemory
...
...
...
leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 2419: 196 nodes malloced for 262162 KB
Process 2419: 26 leaks for 134217760 total leaked bytes.

    26 (128M) << TOTAL >>
      1 (64.0M) ROOT LEAK: 0x10b17c000 [67108864]
      1 (32.0M) ROOT LEAK: 0x105726000 [33554432]
      1 (16.0M) ROOT LEAK: 0x104726000 [16777216]
      1 (8.00M) ROOT LEAK: 0x103f26000 [8388608]
      1 (4.00M) ROOT LEAK: 0x103b26000 [4194304]
      1 (2.00M) ROOT LEAK: 0x103926000 [2097152]
      1 (1.00M) ROOT LEAK: 0x103826000 [1048576]
      1 (512K) ROOT LEAK: 0x1037a6000 [524288]
      1 (256K) ROOT LEAK: 0x103766000 [262144]
      1 (128K) ROOT LEAK: 0x103746000 [131072]
      1 (64.0K) ROOT LEAK: 0x103735000 [65536]
      1 (32.0K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa354007800 [32768]
      1 (16.0K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa354003800 [16384]
      1 (8.00K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa354001800 [8192]
      1 (4.00K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa354000800 [4096]
      1 (2.00K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa354000000 [2048]
      1 (1.00K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353802000 [1024]
      1 (512 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa3535000a0 [512]
      1 (256 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353402fa0 [256]
      1 (128 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353500020 [128]
      1 (64 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353600000 [64]
      1 (32 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353402d40 [32]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353402eb0 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353402ec0 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353500000 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fa353500010 [16]
```

4. You can use [Malloc Debugging Features](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001884-CJBJFIDD)